# Same Main Menu across all forms - winforms .net

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

i want to use one MainMenuStrip across all open Forms in my application. I don't want to display the same MainMenu on all forms, instead the MainMenu should only appear on my MainForm and should be accessible from all my other Forms.

The desired behaviour is the same as in Visual Studio 2013 (probably other versions do it the same way). If one document is floation and you hit the ALT button or any combination e.g. ALT+F, the MainWindow comes to front and the MainMenu is visible although the MainWindow does not get activated it seems. When you hit the ALT button again, focus is returned to the floating Window.

I tried forwarding the messages from a sibling form to the MainForm when the Menu-Key is hit but the MainForm needs to be the Foreground window to process the message - as i can see in the .net sourcecode. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ToolStripManager.cs,1680

I don't want to use MDI - i just wish to have the same Menu behavior as in MDI.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to achieve this i will be very thankfull.

Comment: When menu hotkey is hit remember the form, activate main form, show menu. When menu is closed - activate previous form. Or do I miss something?

Comment: What does this question have to do with a command line interface? That tag seems unrelated.

Comment: the tag was supposed to be cli as in c++/cli

Comment: You have a good answer but i am still curious why you dont want to use mdi but only want to mimic it

Comment: in MDI your childforms are stuck within the bounds of the main form. I need to be able to drag them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic behavior of VS, then here is a way.

```
static class Program
{
    static Form _main;
    static Form _previous;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // simulate some environment here
        _main = new Form1();
        _main.FormClosed += (s, e) => Application.Exit();
        _main.Show();
        new Form2 { Text = "1" }.Show();
        new Form2 { Text = "2" }.Show();
        new Form2 { Text = "3" }.Show();
        Application.Run();
    }

    public static void MenuOpen(Form form)
    {
        _main.Activate();
        _previous = form;
        _main.MainMenuStrip.MenuDeactivate += MainMenuStrip_MenuDeactivate;
        _main.MainMenuStrip.Show();
    }

    static void MainMenuStrip_MenuDeactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _main.MainMenuStrip.MenuDeactivate -= MainMenuStrip_MenuDeactivate;
        _previous.Activate();
        _previous.Focus();
    }
}
```

`Form1` is any form with `MainMenuStrip` defined (aka *main form*), when form is closed application ends.

In `Form2` all you need is to handle menu keypress, one possibility - is preview key down event handler (don't forget to set `KeyPreview=true`):

```
void Form2_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Alt)
        Program.MenuOpen(this);
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: that works pretty great. I have to use ProcessCmdKey with VK_MENU since other controls fish the PreviewKeyDown event. Thanks a lot!